# Httpd Server setup with TLS 1.3

Tags: apache, openssl, webserver, httpd.conf, tls1.3

I am setting up another instance of httpd server in linux machine with TLS 1.3.

httpd server version 2.4.57 openssl 1.1.1

> `which httpd` gives `/etc/sbin/httpd`

and

> `httpd -V` gives config path to `/conf/httpd.conf`

However, I am running my instance from `/app/usr/common/httpd-2.4.57` location and I updated httpd.conf file located in `/app/usr/common/httpd-2.4.57/conf/httpd.conf` with `<VirtualHost *:8443>`

I have also set `SSLProtocol` to `-all +TLSv1.3` along with `SSLCertificateFile`,`SSLCertificateKeyFile`, `SSLCipherSuite`.

Finally, I updated `httpd-ssl.conf` file located in `/app/usr/common/httpd-2.4.57/conf/extra` and updated `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` and have set `DocumentRoot` to `app/usr/htdocs` same as in `httpd.conf` and Included `httpd-ssl.conf` in `httpd.conf` file.

Application runs just fine but TLS still shows 1.2 instead of 1.3. Any idea where it going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the way around:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1.2
```

Anyway you can try use this configurator by mozilla:
[Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/)